# Tomcat starts after issuing 'stop' command

Tags: linux, tomcat

I am seeing very confusing behavior in my tomcat.
I execute:

```
/usr/libexec/tomcat/server stop
```

But instead of stopping tomcat restarts. I issue the command a 2nd time, and then it actually stops. I have tried searching but have not come up with a good way to search 'restarts after stop'. Almost all results talk about scripts to restart tomcat, and stop/start functionality.

Comment: Most likely your system uses a service management system such as `systemd` which automatically restarts something if it stops. Since you're not using that system's stop command, it determines that the process exited abnormally and restarts it. Find out what is responsible for starting tomcat and make use of its stop command instead.

Comment: I think we are using systemd, this makes a lot of sense as being the reason

Answer (score 0):

You can stop tomcat with this command: `your/path/tomcat/bin/./catalina.sh stop` and `your/path/tomcat/bin/./catalina.sh start` to start the server.

If you use linux and your catalina.sh does not have executable permission you need execute this: `chmod +x catalina.sh` before